# Display Message box in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a message box in JavaScript with the following

```
<div id="uLightBox" style="top: 4906px; left: 236px;">
    <div id="lbHeader" class="top"><header>Alert</header></div>
    <div id="lbContent">User cannot be deleted.</div>
    <div id="lbFooter" class="bottom">
        <input type="button" class="flat floatRight" value="OK" id="OK">
    </div>
</div>
```

But this message box is displaying in the middle of the page. Whereas my page is displaying more than hundred records. If my message box is displayed in the middle of the page I have to scroll down each and every time. Please suggest...

Thanks,

Kath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this: style="position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -200px; margin-top: -100px;".

Where 200 and 100 are actually width/2 and height/2.